# jQuery: testing whether the script is running on my local server or live site

Tags: jquery

Is there a simple way to make sure that some jQuery code will run on my local machine (127.0.0.1), but will never run when executed on the live site (www.something.xxx)?

Comment: Don't put it on the live site.

Comment: I have a snippet (Google Analytics, actually) that I do the opposite of what you ask: I want it to run only when live. I don't know if it is a best practice, but for that I use a simple `if` with some `document.location.href` matching.

Comment: Mike W: so far, I'm forced to constantly comment/uncomment the piece of HTML to which the Javascript code is attached. It's a serious waste of time so I should so something about it. Acdcjunior: sounds good, is it secure?

Comment: I don't really know how secure. What "level of security" do you need? This `document.location` variable is the one that google analytics uses, so I'd say it is reliable. In my case, if my code fails, there wouldn't be so much problem. In your case, as you ask for security, it does not seem to be the case, is it?

Comment: I went for it anyway, it seems to work fine. Thanks acdcjunior.